# Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this Error on my Page slider:

> Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /home/globalar/public_html/wp-content/themes/automotive_s1/includes/slider.php on line 30

```
<?php

    if $str = floatval($str); ($post->post_type == "gtcd") {
        the_title();
    if (isset( $fields['price'])) {
        echo ' | <span class="price_slider">'.'  '.$symbols['currency']; 
        echo number_format($fields['price']).'</span> ';
    } else { 
        echo '';
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? PHP gives you an detailed error message. The Method `number_format` expects the first parameter to be a scalar of type double, but your variable `$fields['price']` contains a string. If it contains a double you could cast it.

Comment: You don't know the meaning of `Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given` ? Anyway try to cast `(float)$fields['price'])`

Comment: You're giving `number_format()` a string when it wants a double. Your `$fields['price']` is a double.

Comment: i think you've have a wrong formatted value.. as it is stated by the name of the function, you're to format the number.. so, you should only pass an unformatted number, plain as it is... like 1000 or 10000.0678. i think your variable has , on it

Comment: You should learn what a variable datatype [can contain](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php). Always read the manual before coding!

Comment: @Debflav, your suggestion with (float) before the string removed the error but the Price Value displayed ZERO instead of the variable prices set for each slide.

Comment: @OdofinCaleb `echo (float) "a  string"` prints 0. You should show us what you get inside `$fields['price']`

Comment: Your var `$fields['price']` is probably not formatted but you could simply try, `echo number_format(floatval($fields['price']))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check what value is inside `$fields['price']`.

Just do:

```
var_dump($fields['price']);
```

It's possible you have some spaces or `,` instead of `.`

Comment: Thanks Marcin,, but I have    $fields['price'] in 2 instances on that line, should i var_dump($fields['price']; in both instances. How exactly should the new code look like please

Comment: You can do it at the beginning of this code

Comment: You should after `<?php` add `var_dump($fields['price']);`

Comment: I tried that before, didn't work. I added it just after the <?php. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

```
$fields['price']='8, 9858';
echo number_format((float)$fields['price']);
```

use `(float)` to parse correct way

Answer (score 0):

fix it with define other variabel.

```
$tot=$row['total'];
$total=number_format($tot,2);

$tot2=$tot*1;
$vat=number_format($tot2*10/100,2);
```

maybe help